# Recursive CTE get

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive

I have the following tables:

`Table1`

| id | entity_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |

`Table2` - Same structure as `Table1`

| id | entity_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |

`Table3`

| source_id | destination_id | entity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

`Table1` and `Table2` are both partitions from the same table and `Table3` contains the connections between `ids` on that partition's tables.

One simple example

| id | entity_id | value | table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | table1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | table2 |

| source_id | destination_id | entity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

In this example the two records are connected directly but it's possible for them to be connected indirectly for instance:

| id | entity_id | value | table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | table1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | table2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | tablex |

| source_id | destination_id | entity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

In this example, the values on `Table1` and `Table2` are connected via `TableX` and this can go any level deep.

Now I'm trying to do a query that would return in this case the rows from `Table1` and `Table2`.

I did the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.entity_id, t1.value
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table3 t3 
    ON t1.id = t3.source_id
    UNION 
    SELECT j.id, j.entity_id, j.value
    FROM cte j
    JOIN table3 t3
    ON j.id = t3.source_id
    JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.id = t3.destination_id 
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But it's only returning:

```
1   1   1
```

instead of or similar (I just need the table1 and table2 data)

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/yNLG9-ON

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide scripts to create the test tables and content please.

Comment: @Peter done. https://dbfiddle.uk/yNLG9-ON

Comment: That design doesn't make much sense.  You are keeping references to different tables in the same column.  That alone is already an issue, making it impossible for you to define referential integrity on the database level.  But you are making it even worse by having no indication which table each individual value is a reference to.  Why?

Comment: To clarify, I'm not asking just to bash your schema.  I think the way you've designed it may be part of the reason why you are struggling with a solution.  Knowing whether it has to be like that or not could inform potential answers.

Comment: The entity_id refers to each partition the connection belongs to. I know it's bad design but unfortunately can't be changed.